# How to create your own type with closed set of values, in Scala

Tags: scala

I try mixing in the following trait into my classes, to enjoy something similar to how the type `Boolean` behaves.

```
trait ReadyStates { // well, this is really used like an enumeration
  class ReadyState
  object Ready extends ReadyState 
  object NotReady extends ReadyState
}
```

However, this does not work, as each class this trait is mixed into, creates its own objects. So `Ready` cannot naively compare to `Ready` when passing around return values between members of different classes.

How can I get a custom type, that has its own closed set of allowed values, same as Boolean has `true` and `false` and they can be seamlessly compared across classes?

I looked at enumerations a bit, they didn't look very shiny back then.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like `ReadyStates` should just be an `object`, and other classes just use it's sub-types? Also consider making `ReadyState` sealed and abstract.

Comment: This means `ReadyStates.Ready` wherever it needs to be used. Not quite like `true` and `false`. But yes, it works!

Comment: Not if you `import blah.package.name.ReadyStates._`

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by the comments with @m-z, I ended up using:

```
sealed abstract class ReadyState
object Ready extends ReadyState 
object NotReady extends ReadyState
```

without any wrapper object. Simple.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how Algebraic Sum Types are encoded in Scala. See `Boolean`, `List`, etc. as examples. In fact, that's pretty much the sole reason for `sealed`'s existence.

Comment: I wrote a small implementation of what a proper object-oriented `Boolean` type in Scala would look like in an answer over on Programmers.SE, if you're interested: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/266635/1352

Comment: @JörgWMittag
..not sure how Scala implements Boolean then.. are its values simply types extending it, or something like in your code there? They feel like some sort of literal rather than a type, as per the REPL for `true.getClass`. Just curious now.

Comment: Sorry, the comment about `Boolean`s was misleading. `List` is a better example. In fact, Scala implements `Boolean`s by "magic", i.e. by mapping it to the underlying platform's (JVM, Android, CLI, ECMAScript) primitives. As you can see, the methods are all empty: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/Boolean.scala

Comment: Thought so... so I guess the Scala `object` solutions discussed here, are the best approximation to Scala's `Boolean` literals' behavior (excluding crazy JVM hacking).

Answer (score 3):

To further extend matt's answer, I usually do:

```
sealed trait ReadyState
object ReadyState {
  case object Ready extends ReadyState
  case object NotReady extends ReadyState
}
```

Wrapping the case objects in a companion object `ReadyState` avoids namespace pollution. For instance now you can have another ADT, like

```
sealed trait AnotherState
object AnotherState {
  case object Ready extends AnotherState
  case object NotReady extends AnotherState
}
```

`Ready` and `NotReady` names won't collide, since they're "namespaced" under the respective objects.

Also, using `case objects` (or classes) allows the compiler to check for exhaustive matches.